# neo4j : quick search of a type of relationship between nodes in a list

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

We have a graph with different relationships and a list of nodes. We would like to know the relationships of type "E" between the nodes of this list.

Presently we do like this :

```
With ["0","1","2","10"] as list1
MATCH p=(x)-[:E]-(y) 
WHERE (x.frag IN list1) AND (y.frag IN list1) 
RETURN p
```

It  works for a few nodes but it becomes very slow even with only 100 nodes.

Is there a method to get quicker this result with APOC for example ?

Sincerely.

Comment: I think as a first step, you should: 1. use specific node labels 2. make sure that `frag` is indexed for that node label, i.e. run `CREATE INDEX ON :SomeLabel(frag)`

Comment: Hi. Thank you Gabor for your answer.  When you say "make sure that frag is indexed for that node label", you mean that for a csv file the first line must containt "frag:ID".  Can you confirm that please ?

Answer (score 1):

You may see a big performance boost simply by using labels and indexing your params.    
MATCH p=(x:NODE_LABELX)-[:E]-(y:NODE_LABELY)
 Also check out : https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/01/16/neo4j-graph-model-design-labels-versus-indexed-properties.html

Comment: Hi, Than you for your informations. A added the label and it is quicker but with a list of 150 nodes it is still very slow ! Is there a solution ?

Comment: Did you index the properties you are using too?  How many nodes and relationships does your graph have?